# Stop script working after two specific values are selected

Tags: arcpy, string, multi-values

I have a script tool that runs after values from multivalue box are selected.

[image]

The code is okay and runs withou any mistakes.
But is it possible to make a kind of exception for selection of fields GRAPH and ADVANCED_GRAPH? Because if I run script with two of these boxes activated I get lots of unnecessary data in  TOC.

I tried something like this:

```
all_selected = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
selected = all_selected.split(";") 
arcpy.AddMessage("Working...")

for s in selected:
    if s == "GRAPH;ADVANCED_GRAPH":
    arcpy.AddMessage("ERROR")
```

and this

```
all_selected = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
selected = all_selected.split(";") 
arcpy.AddMessage("Working...")

for s in selected:
    if s == "GRAPH" and if s == "ADVANCED_GRAPH":
    arcpy.AddMessage("ERROR")
```

Both methods don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how your script should look like:

```
all_selected = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
selected = all_selected.split(";")
arcpy.AddMessage("Working...")

if "GRAPH" in selected and "ADVANCED_GRAPH" in selected:
    arcpy.AddMessage("ERROR")

...
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, also after `arcpy.AddMessage("ERROR")` I put `quit()` to stop it working comletely.

Answer (score 2):

I might not be knowledgeable about gis and this is not a complete answer. However it is too long for a comment and for the sake of completeness, I felt the need to add the causes why your trials didn't work:

In the first one, it would work if you did:

```
if all_selected=="GRAPH;ADVANCED_GRAPH":
```

but it would fail for the case when all three of them are selected.

In the second one, there is a logic error. If you want to do it via looping, you need to save the state in an outside variable to make it persist through the iteration.

Also:

```
if s == "GRAPH" and if s == "ADVANCED_GRAPH":
```

is always false since s cannot be both at the same time.

Also, you can always make the script ignore one command while both are selected.